# Jarsigner will not open

Tags: android, executable-jar, jar-signing, jarsigner

Ok I need some help here !! I am working with Windows 7 Home Premium and I have downloaded and installed the jdk6u25x64 and the android sdk. here in lies the problem. I have an app ready to publish and I have made the .apk file. now I need to sign the certificate but when I go to C:/program files/java/jdk/bin and I double click on the jarsigner the binary code box flashes on the screen for like a half a second and closes. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to fix the java CLASSPATH. Anyhow, I would suggest you to export a signed apk directly from Eclipse (see http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard for details)

Answer (score 0):

It's a program that needs command line arguments. Put your jdk\bin directory in the path, then open a DOS box and type 'jarsigner'. It will fail to do anything other than tell you the usage, i.e. what these arguments need to be.